# Oracle 23 throws ORA-26701: XStream process does not exist

Tags: oracle, xstream, oracle-golden-gate

I am presently evaluating Oracle 23's FREE image with XStream using the Oracle Container Registry image having completed the following custom-setup options:

- Created the `recovery_area` path in the image for archive logs.
- Set `db_recovery_file_dest_size` and `db_recovery_file_dest` and `enable_goldengate_replication`.
- Enabled archive log mode and bounced the database after above configurations.
- Created the `c##xsadmin` tablespaces in both the `FREE` and `FREEPDB` databases.
- Created the user `c##xsadmin` in the `FREE` root database assigned to its tablespaces.
- Grant `CREATE_SESSION`, `SET CONTAINER`, `XSTREAM_CAPTURE`, and `XSTREAM_APPLY` to the `c##xsadmin` user.
- Created a local user in `FREEPDB1` that I connect with the following grants: `CONNECT`, `CREATE SESSION`, `CREATE TABLE`, `CREATE SEQUENCE`.
- Created the `c##xsuser` tablespaces in both the `FREE` and `FREEPDB1` databases.
- Created the common user `c##xsuser` in the `FREE` root database specifying the `c##xsuser` tablespaces above.
- Grant `CREATE SESSION`, `SET CONTAINER`, `SELECT ON V$DATABASE`, `FLASHBACK`, `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE`, and `EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE` to the `c##xsuser` common user.

With those steps in place, I begin to create the XStream outbound server by running the following using the `c##xsadmin` user in the `FREE` database:

```
DECLARE
  tables  DBMS_UTILITY.UNCL_ARRAY;
  schemas DBMS_UTILITY.UNCL_ARRAY;
BEGIN
    tables(1)  := NULL;
    schemas(1) := 'debezium';
  DBMS_XSTREAM_ADM.CREATE_OUTBOUND(
    server_name     =>  'dbzxout',
    table_names     =>  tables,
    schema_names    =>  schemas);
END;
```

Finally, I reconnect as the `sys` user with `sysdba` role and execute:

```
DBMS_XSTREAM_ADM.ALTER_OUTBOUND(
  server_name  => 'dbzxout',
  connect_user => 'c##xsuser');
END;
```

In the container I see XStream and GG start:

```
The following output is now a tail of the alert.log:
  Current log# 3 seq# 6 mem# 0: /opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/redo03.log
2023-11-03T16:07:51.090708+00:00
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 7 (LGWR switch),  current SCN: 3168082
  Current log# 1 seq# 7 mem# 0: /opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/redo01.log
2023-11-03T16:07:51.105474+00:00
NET  (PID:920): Archived Log entry 5 added for B-1146462010.T-1.S-6 ID 0x548cb679 LAD:1 [krse.c:4846]
2023-11-03T16:07:52.900689+00:00
First applied SCN for apply w/ object number 70773 and subscriber sequence number 1 is updated to SCN: 0 (0x0000000000000000)
2023-11-03T16:07:52.907440+00:00
First applied SCN of the XStream path from capture (CAP$_DBZXOUT_1) to propagation () to apply (DBZXOUT) is set to SCN: 3166601 (0x0000000000305189)
Resize operation completed for file# 3, fname /opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/sysaux01.dbf, old size 573440K, new size 583680K
2023-11-03T16:07:59.672209+00:00
Resize operation completed for file# 3, fname /opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/sysaux01.dbf, old size 583680K, new size 604160K
Resize operation completed for file# 3, fname /opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/sysaux01.dbf, old size 604160K, new size 614400K
2023-11-03T16:08:01.292894+00:00
Resize operation completed for file# 3, fname /opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/sysaux01.dbf, old size 614400K, new size 645120K
2023-11-03T16:08:04.237279+00:00
Resize operation completed for file# 3, fname /opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/sysaux01.dbf, old size 645120K, new size 655360K
2023-11-03T16:08:04.286567+00:00
Resize operation completed for file# 3, fname /opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/sysaux01.dbf, old size 655360K, new size 686080K
2023-11-03T16:08:06.824192+00:00
Resize operation completed for file# 3, fname /opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/sysaux01.dbf, old size 686080K, new size 696320K
2023-11-03T16:08:06.857728+00:00
Resize operation completed for file# 3, fname /opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/sysaux01.dbf, old size 696320K, new size 727040K
2023-11-03T16:08:08.921850+00:00
 : 
LOGMINER: Gathering statistics on logminer dictionary. (incremental, nonparallel)
```

Running `SELECT dbms_apply_process.get_apply#('DBZXOUT');` outputs:

```
1000
```

Running `SELECT STATE FROM V$PROPAGATION_RECEIVER;` outputs:

```
Waiting for message from propagation sender
```

Running `SELECT SERVER_NAME, CONNECT_USER, CAPTURE_NAME, SOURCE_DATABASE, CAPTURE_USER, QUEUE_OWNER FROM ALL_XSTREAM_OUTBOUND;` outputs:

```
DBXOUT | C##XSUSER | CAP$_DBXOUT_1 | FREE | C##XSADMIN | C##XSADMIN
```

I have also checked `DBA_ALERT_HISTORY` and `DBA_OUTSTANDING_ALERTS` for good measure and I don't get any results, so I'm really baffled as to why when my client attempts to attach to the XStream process, I get the error:

```
Caused by: oracle.streams.StreamsException: ORA-26701: XStream process DBZXOUT does not exist
```

I compared this to my steps for Oracle 19 and the only difference I found was needing to assign `XSTREAM_CAPTURE` and `XSTREAM_APPLY` roles rather than using the `DBMS_XSTREAM_AUTH.GRANT_ADMIN_PRIVILEGE` package and it works for that version.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I may have done incorrectly?